# What is the name of this houseplant, and how can I prevent it from drying out?

Tags: identification, houseplants, watering, plant-care, dryness

One of my friends gave me this plant as present about two weeks ago. Now it`s starting to dry out, while retaining green leaves (without yellowing). At first I watered it every day, but now water it every two days. What is the name of this plant and how can I save it?
[image]

Comment: I'd start with taking the foil off the pot - while it prettifies the pot for gifting, it inhibits air and water (and can impede drainage, depending how it's been applied.)

Answer (score 6):

Definitely an Impatiens variety (busy lizzie) - can't tell how tall it is, but it looks remarkably like I. walleriana - if its taller than it seems, it'll be one of the New Guinea hybrids. I note the black specks on the plate its standing on - I'm assuming that's soil from the top of the pot from when you water. That indicates the soil is too high in the pot, and when you water, it washes over the side - it also may mean the plant is too dry when you do water, or that insufficient water penetrates the rootball because it washes over the edge of the pot before it penetrates.

I'd also ask whether you leave it sitting in water at the bottom, and whether the drainage holes in the bottom of the pot are free and open, or covered in that tin foil. If the plate is always full of water, and the drainage holes are open, then the plant is sitting in water too long, but that doesn't seem likely given the amount of soil specks on the plate.

These plants like dampish soil and grow well in shady areas, though they do need some light, flowering happily in sun or shade, so long as their roots don't dry out. I'd be inclined to turn the plant out of its pot, very carefully so as not to disturb the rootball too much, nor break any of the very fragile stems, and put it in a larger pot with a gap between the soil level and the top of the pot, so that when you water, you can get a good amount in there without soil washing out. You'd obviously need some potting compost to fill the gaps round the sides of the rootball in a larger pot, but I wouldn't disturb the rootball too much - it may stop flowering for a while if you do, though it will recover. Water in well, then ongoing, water when the surface of the compost feels just dry to the touch, and give it plenty of water, emptying out excess from the plate its standing on after 30 minutes.

I'd add that, at the moment, it appears reasonably healthy, but check the leaves and stems carefully - the leaves look a little shiny (though that may be a trick of the light in the picture) and this can sometimes mean its infested with aphids of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an  Impatiens, have the leaves been oiled?  They are so shiny, that may not be the best thing for them if they have been oiled.  I agree with getting the foil off and having a look at the roots, re-pot in fresh dirt.

Answer (score -1):

This may seem a bit obvious, but maybe go back to watering it everyday? ! Is the soil most or dry when you water it? If it is dry (no moisture, crumbles apart) you need to water it more often or give it more water when you do).

Comment: -1, because this does not answer the identification part.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly I cannot identify the plant, but I would start by repotting the plant.  If the plant looks to be root bound, spread up the roots and place into a larger pot.  If it is not root bound something about the same size should do fine.

Comment: -1, because this does not answer the identification part.